# Problems while using Factory, Abstract class and Models in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, factory, abstract

i am using codeigniter and i want to use my factory library (or if you know a better way) to create a user, the user is a class that extends an abstract model.
and i get the error that i didn't include the abstract class. i dont know how to include it in codeigniter.
i can't just load a abstract class that extends model.
here is my code:

```
    class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('factory');

    }

    function register(){
        $user = $this->factory->create('doctor'); // returns 'doctor_m' or 'patient_m'
        $this->load->model($user); 
        $this->$user->addUser();
    }
}

abstract class User_m extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    abstract protected function addUser();
    abstract protected function getUser();
}

class Doctor_m extends User_m{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function addUser() {
        echo "doctor";
    }

    function getUser() {
    }
}

class Patient_m extends User_m{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function addUser() {
        echo 'patient';
    }

    function getUser() {
    }
}

class factory{
    function create($type){
        if($type == 'doctor') return 'doctor_m';
        else return 'patient_m';
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this? is this the best way to write it in MVC? needs help i am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

If the base class is in the models directly along side the other models, just add `require_once( 'filename.php' );` before you begin  the class code.

If your base class is in the libraries (or another folder), I'd suggest you move it as I wouldn't consider that an appropriate location. If I build a base model class, I put it in the model directory....

Comment: i can't, user_m extends model, so i can't just include it.